# How to disable home and back buttons?

Tags: android

How to disable home and back buttons?

Comment: you can override onBackPressed in Activity to prevent closing activity.

Answer (score 0):

Home Button:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

To disable Home Button:

```
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
```

To disable Back Button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Do nothing or catch the keys you want to block
  }
```

To add this in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```